# Return the smallest number from the list. It should return -1 when an empty list is encountered

Tags: python, recursion

Here is a recursion program

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, -3, 5]
numbers0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numbers1 = []

def smallest(myList):
    if len(myList) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return min(myList[0], smallest(myList[1:]))

print(smallest(numbers))
print(smallest(numbers0))
print(smallest(numbers1))
```

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Why not `def smallest(lst): return min(lst) if lst else -1`?

Comment: must use recursion

Answer (score 0):

If you just want return the smallest number from the list, you don't need to use recursion

```
numbers = [1,2,3,-3,5] 
numbers0 = [1,2,3,4,5] 
numbers1 = []

def smallest(myList): 
    if len(myList)==0: 
        return -1 
    else: 
        return min(myList)

print(smallest(numbers)) 
print(smallest(numbers0)) 
print(smallest(numbers1))
```

Output:

```
-3
1
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this question was pretty easy:

```
#--Lists--
numbers = [1,2,3,-3,5]
numbers0 = [1,2,3,4,5]
numbers1 = []

#--Store all list in a list--

myList = [numbers, numbers0, numbers1]

#--List to store the minimum values--

a = []

#--For loop on each list--

for i in myList:
  if len(i)==0: #--If it is empty print -1
    print(-1)
  else: #--If it is not empty, find the minimum-- 
    b = min(i)
    a.append(b) #--And then append in a--

print(a) #--Show the values of a--
```

This should do it and is pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do something like this.

```
numbers = [1,2,3,-3,5] 
numbers0 = [1,2,3,4,5] 
numbers1 = []

#make a list of all the lists but in sorted order

n = [sorted(numbers),sorted(numbers0),sorted(numbers1)]

#then take the first element of each list. If list is empty, use -1 

x = [-1 if not i else i[0] for i in n]

#x will now contain the smallest values from each list

print (x)
```

**Output**

```
[-3, 1, -1]
```

Another way to do this would be:

```
#create a list with all the lists

n = [numbers, numbers0, numbers1]

#run thru them and identify the minimum value of each list
#if list is empty, then -1

x = [-1 if not i else min(i) for i in n]

#print the final result

print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
[-3, 1, -1]
```